# If event $A\cap B \to C$, what can we say about the probability $P(A\cap B)$ and P(C)

Tags: probability

I know that, if $A\to B$, then $A \subseteq B$, hence $P(A) \leq P(B)$.

consider events:
$$A: x = y$$
$$B: y = z$$
$$C: x = z$$

then $A\cap B \to C$, can we conclude though:
$$P(A\cap B) = P(C)$$

Comment: "if $A\to B$, then $B \subseteq A$" Sure about this?

Comment: sry, it's the other way round. but my final question stands=)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localized.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct about the step that $A \cap B \subset C$. However, you'd also have to show $C \subseteq A \cap B $ if you want to show that the two sets are equal.

In particular, I don't think the statement is true -- suppose x, y, and z are the results from tossing fair coins X, Y, and Z.

The probability that all three coins show the same thing (eventa $A \cap B$) is 1/4, where as the probability that coins X and Y show the same thing (event $C$) is 1/2.

Comment: You can select one of these (or upvote them) to let others know you got an answer in the thread

Comment: I think my reputation level doesn't allow me to vote.

Answer (score 0):

No, not quite. Knowing that $A\cap B \rightarrow C$ is not enough to conclude that $A\cap B = C$. For the two events to be equal, $C \rightarrow A \cap B$ must be satisfied as well.

This is not true for the given example, as we can construct an outcome $\omega \in C$ such that $x=z$, but $y \neq x,z$. Since $\omega$ cannot be in $A$ or $B$, $\omega \notin A\cap B$. This proves that $P(A\cap B) \neq P(C)$.